# kivy, Checking if two widgets overlap after rotation

Tags: python, kivy

Working with kivy, how can I check if a widget overlap another widget after they have been rotated. Using the collide_widget method does not take the rotation into account, so the following code snippet prints out "is colliding" even you can see that the rectangles are not overlapping. Is there something else clever I can do with kivy that would allow me to check a collision with rectangles after they have been rotated?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import PopMatrix, PushMatrix
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Rotate

class RotatableRect(Widget):
    def __init__(self, angle=0, **kwargs):
        super(RotatableRect, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        with self.canvas.before:
            PushMatrix()
            self.rot = Rotate()
            self.rot.angle = angle
            self.rot.origin = self.center
            self.rot.axis = (0, 0, 1)
            self.rect = Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)

        with self.canvas.after:
            PopMatrix()


class MainWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.rect1 = RotatableRect(pos=[10, 100], size=[100, 50])
        self.rect2 = RotatableRect(pos=[100, 50], size=[100, 50], angle=45)
        self.add_widget(self.rect1)
        self.add_widget(self.rect2)

        if self.rect1.collide_widget(self.rect2):
            print 'is colliding'

class TheApp(App):
    def build(self):
        parent = Widget()
        parent.add_widget(MainWidget())
        return parent

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TheApp().run()
```

Comment: Remember that anything you do in canvas instructions only affects the rendering of the widget. It won't change the widgets' actual positions and therefore collide_widget will not take this into account. As for how to actually detect collision, you would need to look at implementing an algorithm like Separating Axis Theorem. [KivEnt](https://github.com/Kovak/KivEnt) may support this already.

Comment: Thanks for your info, I've been reading about SAT and I want to try to implement it (for example this way: http://www.gamedev.net/page/reference/index.html/_/technical/game-programming/2d-rotated-rectangle-collision-r2604 ). But the problem is that I would then need the points of the corners on the rectangles like they are on the canvas (in screen space). Do you have any clue how/if I can get that?

Comment: You can just start with the corner points, then perform the rotation on them. You should look at the [`Scatter`](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.scatter.html) widget - it supports rotation and has overridden the point manipulation methods (such as `to_window`) to apply the transformation. It will work out of the box with `collide_point`, though you're still on your own for `collide_widget`.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Rotabox](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.rotabox) widget in the [kivy-garden](https://github.com/kivy-garden/).
I made it originally for this exact collision+rotation purpose, although it evolved a lot since then.

Firstly, include `rotabox.py` in your project.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle
from rotabox import Rotabox


class RotatableRect(Rotabox):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RotatableRect, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            self.rect = Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)


class MainWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)    
        self.rect1 = RotatableRect(pos=[10, 100], size=[100, 50])
        self.rect2 = RotatableRect(pos=[100, 50], size=[100, 50], angle=45)
        self.add_widget(self.rect1)
        self.add_widget(self.rect2)

        # for a stationary rotabox, it's essential to wait for it to setup, 
        # before any collision checks
        self.rect1.bind(ready=self.check)

    def check(self, *args):
        if self.rect1.collide_widget(self.rect2):
            print '  is colliding'    

class TheApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TheApp().run()
```

The rotation itself is handled by the widget as long as an angle is given and the default origin of rotation is the widget's center.

Comment: is it possible to use your Rotabox in combination with a Scatter? or should i try to implement the simple rotated collision detection of a rectangle myself as 'AddOnBehavior' ?

Comment: After unsuccessful efforts to combine the two, Rotabox has touch interactivity added.